# Understand unknown Base64 algorithm

Tags: base64, decode

I have a problem with string decryption. I think this is some kind of base64 encoding, but i'm not sure.

Source: 80009861
Result: wEpISZVq4gLkLSFdOxG3qQ==

I need your help with understanding this algorithm of encryption.

Comment: What's the context? Do you know if the input is being passed through a cryptographic hash function?

Comment: i guess it's being passed through some kind of additional encryption cause
it couldn't be decompiled with default base64 decompiler

Comment: Is the source always a decimal number or can it be any string?

Comment: Could you provide the result for 80009862, for instance?